# How can I increment or decrement pointer argument value in function call in C in one line?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo2(int *px, int *py)
{
    int sum = *px + *py;
    *px = *px + 1;
    *py = *py - 1;
    printf("foo2 : res=%d x=%d y=%d\n", sum, *px, *py);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int x = 4, y = 7, res;
    res = foo2(&(x++), &(y--));
    printf("%d", res);

    return 0;
}
```

I need to increment `x`, decrement `y`, then I need to pass them in `foo` function as arguments.

I have `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`. Also I tried to use `x + 1` and `y - 1` instead of `x++` and `y++`.

How can I increment `x` and `y` values and pass pointer to them in `foo2` function call? Is it possible?

Comment: on one statement `foo2((x++, &x), (y--, &y));` or `foo2((++x, &x), (--y, &y));` or `foo2((x+=1, &x), (y--=1, &y));`  all doing the same and corresponding to `I need to increment x, decrement y, then I need to pass them in foo function as arguments`, notice *x* and *y* are given with their new value to *foo*

Comment: @bruno I guess there is a minus too much in `y--=1`, but good comment.

Comment: Or `res = x++, y--, foo2(&x, &y);` with focus on *one line* and you don't want the changes to be made inside of the function call.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio yes double minus was a typo, and yes lot of ways to do ... and to be less readable than in several lines or just doing `int x = 5, y = 6, res; ...` ^^

Comment: @bruno That would indeed would make much more sense. It makes so much sense I have to ask back. I can't believe I didn't see that. I need a coffee.

Comment: @diduk001 Is this just an example and you want to use in- and decrementations and the function call inside of a loop or anything like that because to just initialize the variables with the correct values would in your given example be much more appropriate.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, it is just an example, I understand that doing like that is bad practice, it's just interesting for me to discover features of the language

Comment: @diduk001 The clear question of yours distracted me to care on the example. For future questions, you should just focusing on how to do this specific task. The whole example is good and I appreciate your effort but maybe distract others by looking behind your algorithm and distracts them from what you want to ask for in particular. Or better provide an example that makes sense in the context of your question and back up your thoughts.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Ok! Thank you for this comment, I will do so!

Comment: Rarely does one see such dedication to introducing difficult-to-debug code:)   Put another way, stop doing 'clever' stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the comma operator:

```
res = foo2((x++, &x), (y--, &y));
```

However this is not very readable, so unless you have a really good reason it is better to write it as three separate statements:

```
x++;
y--;
res = foo2(&x, &y);
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is not readable, but I want to know if I can do this, just kind of experiments. Anyway thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add some points here:

**C**:

In c both the prefix and postfix increment returns the `rvalue`. So that's the reason you will get an error when you try to get address of post/pre-increment in c.

**C++**:

But in c++, the `prefix (++x)` returns `lvalue` and `postfix(x++)` returns a `rvalue`. So in c++, `&(++x)` is correct whereas `&(x++)` throws the error.

***Note:***

I encourage you to read about this a bit more. It will help you a lot to understand much better.

Comment: I'd encourage never writing code like that even if it's legal - it's fragile as it creates some ordering dependencies within a single statement.  That can be very bug-prone as it can be hard to understand exactly what's happening in that single statement.  And because of those ordering dependencies, use of multiple instances of such code in unsequenced statements such as function calls risks undefined behavior should there be dependencies between the multiple instances.  If you want to increment `x` and pass its address to a function, do it in two lines.