# How can I create a pointer to a new object (which is decremented value of a variable) as argument in C?

Tags: c, pointers

**I understand that it's bad practice to do like that, it's just interesting for me to discover language's fratures.**

I have already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62970173/13283436) question, where I need to increment value of variable. But now I don't want to change `x` variable value.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int *px) {
    *px = *px - 1;
    return *px * 2;
}

int main() {
    int res;
    int x = 4;
    res = foo((x--, &x));
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass pointer to `x - 1` value as argument, but not to change `x` value. Also if it's possible, it's interesting for me to know if I can do this in one function call.

Comment: `foo(int *px)` has a single argument. Why are passing two arguments? `res=foo(x--,&x)`.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula OP is using the comma operator.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula `(x--, &x)` is not two arguments - it's one, using the comma operator.

Comment: `x--` in `(x--, &x)` is decrementing `x` and passes a pointer to `x` to `foo`. If you don't want the decrementation just use `res = foo(&x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the argument to `foo` needs to be a pointer to some `int` object which contains the value `x-1`.  If you don't want that object to be `x` itself, then necessarily you have to create another one somehow.

The simplest approach is to just define it as a temporary variable, as in
Sai Sreenivas's answer: `int var = x - 1; foo(&var);`.  If you want to avoid polluting your namespace with the variable `var`, you can enclose everything in a set of braces so that it is a separate compound statement:

```
int x = 4;
int res;
{
   int var = x - 1;
   res = foo(&var);
}
int var = 17; // unrelated to the previous var
```

Another approach, less readable but more compact, is to use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
res = foo(&(int){x-1});
```

This creates a temporary object of type `int` that has no name, initializes it with the value `x-1`, and passes its address to `foo`.

Note that if `foo` modifies the value of `*px`, those modifications will be made to this temporary object. But you will have no way of retrieving its new value after `foo` returns, so it is effectively lost.

Compound literals are a somewhat more obscure feature of the language, so some readers of your code may have trouble recognizing what's going on.  Thus I'd suggest avoiding this approach unless there is a compelling reason to use it, beyond just brevity.

Comment: Isn't a compound literal c++ only ?

Comment: @Tudor: No, they've been supported in C since C99.  The page I linked has references to the standard at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

**If I've understood you correctly**, you want to do something like this I guess :

```c
res = foo(&(x - 1));
```

But you can't :

When you try to access the address of `x - 1` you will get an error because you are trying to access the address of a temporary variable `x - 1` (variable which is not actually stored).

> I want to pass a pointer to x - 1 value as an argument, but not to change x value.

If you want to do this, you need to store `x - 1` in another variable and send the address of that:

```c
int var = x - 1;
res = foo(&var);
```

***Note:***

I think I have mentioned some points about lvalue and rvalue in that answer. So technically `x - 1` is a rvalue here. So you &(`rvalue`) is not possible.

Comment: Take a peek to the accepted answer in the link given in the question.

Comment: As there are two pair of parentheses, the code does not pass the address of 3 (like `&3`), but decrement the value of the variable and then pass the address of that variable.

Comment: @ssd *Take a peek to the accepted answer in the link given in the question.* The linked question does not have the restriction this question does of not modifying the value of the variable in the code that calls the `foo()` function.  This answer properly states "you can't" **because the `foo()` function as currently posted in the question always modifies the variable at the address it's passed**.  The ***ONLY*** way to call `foo()` and not modify a variable is to **not pass that variable to `foo()`**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : I'm aware of that, but this proposed answer above is constructed as if the code in the question is trying to pass the address of a value ("3"), not a variable. It seemed to me that way. I may have misunderstood though.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass pointer to `x - 1` value as argument

There are actual two options, which you could mean with that statement.

*Method A:*

If you mean you want to use `&(x - 1)`, this would attempt to gain a pointer to rvalue `3` as `(x - 1)` gains `3`, which isn't possible. An rvalue does not have an address because it is not stored in an lvalue object in memory, which you could reassign with any other `int` value. `&` can only be used at lvalue objects.

*Method B:*

If you want to get a pointer which points one size of the object before a scalar object, doing so invokes undefined behavior. It is even undefined behavior for the first element of an array.

It would only be valid if `x` would be something like `x[1]` and denote an array element after the first one, which isn't the case here.

You can't store an `int` value at this location inside of the function, so I don't understand how that would makes sense either.

> How can I create a pointer to a new object (which is decremented value of a variable) as argument in C?

The only way, to achieve this to create a separate variable in the caller, assign `x + 1` to this one and pass a pointer to this variable to `foo`.

```
int y = x + 1;
res = foo(&y);
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting title and for the whole answer

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is to keep the `x` value the same after the function finishes. Since you can not track what happens to `x` before it is pushed as parameter, you can not revert the changes made. What i mean by this is, if in the function you do `*px = *px - 123` you can revert it back, but you can not see how the calling statement looks like (it can be `foo((x = x-1, &x));` or `foo((x = x+1, &x));`) and you will have no information inside the `foo` function about how the operation changed `x`.

But i might have a solution for it. A macro (well experimenting means experimenting please never use something like this xD )

```
int foo (int* px)
{
    // what you do in the function, you undo in the function.
    *px = *px - 1;
    int nReturnValue = *px;
    *px = *px + 1;
    return nReturnValue;
}


#define bar(x, number)                     \
printf("%d\n", foo((x = x + number, &x))); \
x = x - number;


int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    bar(x, 10);
    printf("Now the value is the same: %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE: THIS CODE SHOULD ONLY HAVE EXPERIMENTAL PURPOSES, DO NOT USE!**

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio He asked exactly this: How can i make it in one line and keep the x value the same. Is it one line: Yes, does the value of x change: No. So this is the closest he could get to an answer.

Comment: No, that's not what OP asked for. OP seemed s/he wanted to getting a pointer to a *presumed* new created object with the value of the incremented value by using the ampersand operator on an rvalue. S/he asks how to achieve that. It is incorrect and impossible, but this is the main question.

Comment: Thats what you do with the comma operator... I understand what you dont get it. If you only read the title, yes... what you said is the question. But look at what he is trying to do. He only asked how to keep the `x` with the same value after calling the function...

Comment: The problem is everything OP said and the whole example doesn't make sense. "He only asked how to keep the `x` with the same value after calling the function*" - That's not what s/he asked for and doesn't make even sense. Why would OP have an interest in changing the value  of `x` at the function call only when s/he want to pass a pointer? That is not what s/he wants. OP wants to create an object by the rvalue and want to have a pointer to it, which is not possible. This whole question is whole pack of mayhem.